# sorting linked list implementation, getting the same list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, logic, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement a bubble sort on a linked list. However, I get access errors:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x001A8C7B in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

This error occur in my bubble sort method:

```
if (current->data > nextElement->data)
```

call in main

```
list1.SortList();
```

struct

```
struct IntNode
{
    int data;
    IntNode * next;
};
```

bubble sort

```
void NodeSLList::SortList()
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return;

    IntNode * current = head;
    IntNode * nextElement = current->next;
    IntNode * temp = NULL;

    int changed = 1;


    while (changed)
    {
        changed = 0;
        for (current; current != NULL; current = current->next)
        {
            if (current->data > nextElement->data) //ACCESS ERROR
            {
                temp = current;
                current = nextElement;
                nextElement = temp;
                changed = 1;
            }
            nextElement = nextElement->next;
        }

    }
```

}

---

I changed the inside of the loop to:

```
for (current; (current != NULL) && (nextElement = NULL); )
{
    if (current->data > nextElement->data)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        current->next = nextElement->next;
        nextElement->next = temp;
        changed = 1;
    }
    current = current->next;
    nextElement = nextElement->next;
}
```

However, my list continues to output the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `nextElement` is NULL too. Consider a list of two elements:

```
A --> B --> NULL
```

On your first iteration through the `while` loop, first you'll have `current == A` and `nextElement == B`... and then you'll have `current == B` and `nextElement == NULL`, which you will still try to grab `data` off of, hence your access violation.

Just change your loop condition from:

```
for (current; current != NULL; current = current->next)
```

to

```
for (current; current != NULL && nextElement = NULL; current = current->next)
```

And maybe even move the `nextElement = nextElement->next` into the loop line too, for added clarity.

That solves your access violation, but it doesn't solve your "loop isn't actually sorting" problem. That's because you're not actually changing anything in your loop. Consider the above loop again and assume it's backwards and you need to switch it:

```
A --> B --> NULL
^     ^
crt   next
```

After your swap, you will end up with

```
A --> B --> NULL
^     ^
next  current
```

You successfully swapped the pointers, but you didn't actually change the list ordering. What you do need to change are the `next` pointers. Specifically, three of them: `current`'s, `nextElement`'s, and `current`'s parent's.

Comment: I changed the inside of the for loop to :
`temp = current->next;
current->next = nextElement->next;
nextElement->next = temp;`
however the list is still the same.

Comment: @user2577345 You changed two `next` pointers, you have to change three.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (current; current != NULL; current = current->next)
```

Here current may point to the last node, at this point nextElement = NULL.

so `nextElement->data` is invalid.